# Could not parse date: Unparseable date with Spring

Tags: java, spring, date, parsing, illegalargumentexception

I'm stuck entering data from my spring boot application to my mysql database.
I throw this exception:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Date'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "2018-06-17"]
```

in my classic article I did this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    private Date dataCreazione;
```

in the class controller this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/aggiungi", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String inserimentoarticolo(@RequestParam(value = "dataCreazione") Date date, 
            @ModelAttribute("newArticolo") Articolo a, @ModelAttribute("newCategoria") Categoria c, 
            @ModelAttribute("newIva") Iva i, BindingResult result,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) throws ServletException, IOException {


        c=categoriaService.selectById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("categorie")));
        i=ivaService.selectById(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ive")));

        a.setCodArticolo(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("codArticolo")));
        a.setDescrizione(request.getParameter("descrizione"));
        a.setDataCreazione(date);
        a.setCategoria(c);
        a.setIva(i);


        articoloService.insArticolo(a);

        return "index";
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat data = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        data.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(data, false));
    }
```

in the jsp this:

```
<form:input id="dataCreazione" path="dataCreazione" type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

what did i do wrong?

Thank you